Cppcheck: MISRA missing configuration and internal error
I am using cppcheck extension with VSCode for MISRA static analysis.
Here is my platform.ini command line:
check_tool = cppcheck
check_flags =
    cppcheck: --addon=./scripts/misra.json --addon=cert --addon=threadsafety --addon=y2038 --suppress=*:*stm32l0xx_hal.c

I have added MISRA headline txt file from here
I have also taken MISRA addon scripts from official repo
While running pio check in the powershell, I get following set of errors:
[high:error] Because of missing configuration, misra checking is incomplete. There can be false negatives! Unknown array size, please review configuration [misra-config]

src\main.c:0:[high:error] Bailing out from checking since there was an internal error: Failed to execute 'C:\.platformio\penv\Scripts\python.exe C:\\.platformio\packages\tool-cppcheck\addons\runaddon.py scripts\misra.py --cli --rule-texts=scripts/misra2018.txt C:\PlatformIO\Projects\L010_test\src\main.c.18884.dump'. {file: C:/.platformio/packages/framework-stm32cubel0/Drivers/CMSIS/Include/cmsis_gcc.h, linenr: 181, column: 50, severity: style, message: A function should not contain unused parameters\t, addon: misra, errorId: c2012-2.7, extra: Advisory} [internalError]

Is there something that needs to be done in the configuration file? though I am unable to locate misra-config
Can someone please help me understand this error or what I might be doing wrong here.

1.) The CERT addon is not in the open source version anymore. It is now availably in the premium version only (https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/).  But maybe  you can find it in the Repo ;) . But first: remove the --addon=cert 2.) The linked MISRA headline file is for MISRA-C:2023 not MISRA-C:2012. At least that's what the file is named after. But the Repo says 2012/2023. Not sure but maybe that could be something to look into. What is scripts/misra2018.txt?

1.) I tried removing --addon=cert, it didn't make any difference. 2.) I have also tried using 2012 rule sets from this here: https://github.com/tim-rose/makeshift/blob/master/data/cppcheck/misra.txt scripts/misra2018.txt is the name of the file which contains rules.

Can you run the prompt in the error message? E.g. python.exe addons\runaddon.py --cli --rule-texts=scripts\misra2018.txt [etc.] Check if all the path can be found and maybe check the slashes in paths to match your operating system(for Windows \ instead of /)

@rzickler It thrown Python was not found

Is python installed? Is python in your PATH? Check e.g. with python.exe --version. I don't know platformio but there seems to be a python binary here C:\.platformio\penv\Scripts\python.exe.

As you are using the "official" MISRA headlines, this suggests there's something wrong with our config file... could you email me at chair dot c at misra dot org dot uk and I'll try and work out what's wrong!

misra-config is written by the misra addon when there is something unknown in the code. Typically there is some declarations not seen by Cppcheck. A possible solution could be to provide some more -I or -D flags.
It's not a problem in your code but rather a problem in the Cppcheck configuration.
